# How can I generate 3 outputs (green/red/off) with a single toggle switch (VERY SMALL)

Tags: led

Disclaimer - I have little to no knowledge of any of this. I'm in over my head and appreciate your help and I appreciate in advance the lamens terms you've chosen to answer with.

I'm trying to create a very small LED light that will have a single button.

First push of the button LED turns green, 2nd push, LED turns RED, 3rd Push - LED turns off.

Would ideally use a 2032 coin cell battery and the whole apparatus would need to fit in the mold about 32mm diameter (height as low as possible)

What components would I need (any links or part numbers also very appreciated!)

Thank you!!

Comment: You will need a state machine. Which can be implemented in different ways.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the super fast reply! Again, i'm BRAND new at this - I will google a state machine :)

Comment: 2 bit counter which counts 0,1,2,0,1...

Comment: You want a [PIC10F200](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239F.pdf). Or still better, a [PIC10LF320/322](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001585D.pdf). The CR2032 won't operate an LED at 20 mA, though. So look for a high efficiency type that works on 2 mA (which is still pushing things.) If you use the MCU to PWM the LED, you can get the average current down to the level that the CR2032 likes a lot better, too.

Comment: MCU in a SOT23-6 or SO-8 package if you are hand wiring, perhaps some QFN package for a thinner solution if you are using a board.  Get it all working on a breadboard with a DIP version of the MCU first.

Comment: While you're googling, go look up "switch bounce."  This can be addressed with software if you use an MCU.

Comment: Although an expert can easily do this with a simple shift register in a 5mm TSOP package, 74HC164PW and another chip to generate the pattern that disables Green when Red is turned ON with a couple tiny surface mount caps and resistor , on a tiny PCB, in a package only twice the  battery thickness, unless you know how to design a board like this, what's the point?

Comment: Do you want to learn how to do this, or just get 'er done  http://cuc.ucc.ie/CS1101/David%20Tarnoff.pdf

Comment: your All caps in the title is what we call an OXYMORON

Comment: The OP says he has no knowledge; I fear that state machines are not what he is really needing. Let's keep the things **simple**. _First option:_ two switches, the first one is ON/OFF, the second one is RED/GREEN. _Second Option_: a three state switch that does this job **phisically**. I had a cheap chinese lamp that has a clever designed switch that cycles by those three states at every click: 1) OFF 2) Four white leds 3) color changing led. I will try to research for this.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple.

- for 2 D FF registers ( 1 IC) or an 8 bit SHift Register ( 1 IC) driving the LEDs Gn & Rd  the logic states are initially 0,0. Then with each clock input going high (1) by either pressing or releasing the momentary ( your choice), the outputs look like this:

The cost is nothing compared to the time you spend making it and not much difference in cost to a microcontroller if you know how to code.  Both require some board wiring or a PCB with solder skills.

```
    State    Gn Rd
    1        0  0  Both Off
    2        1  0  Green On
    3        0  1  Grn Off, Red On
    1        0  0  repeat back to state 1

    HLMP-Yzzz      Green clear     240 mcd @ 2.10V @ 20mA  572 nmD 45 deg Radial 3mm 
    WP710A10SRD/J  Red   diffused 1300 mcd @ 1.85V @ 20mA  640 nmD 40 deg Radial 3mm
```

Since the Red is slightly brighter but from direct driving at 3V the battery resistance will drop then the chip output will drop so you wont get nor will you need 20mA. Meaning you wont need a series resistor to limit current unless you want the battery to last longer with a dimmer output say 2mA.

```
    74HC164N       CMOS SHift Register 8 bit IC 14 pin DIP 
    74HC4002       CMOS NOR Gates quad 2-in  IC 14 pin DIP
```

Someone else may volunteer to connect the pins.

Comment: I like CR2032 + capacitor + SOT23 MCU + PB + LED. Adaptable, as needed, without any part changes.

Comment: Thank you all! Tony - the point is a board game piece that is either active (green) inactive (red) or in storage when not in play (off)

Comment: Then your question is incomplete as there are many inputs and outputs , so a tri state bus for off and a single output 1 or 0 to drive the LED is more efficient on I/O lines, but now you need 1 battery per square instead of a more efficient solution using a cross-point matrix for all I/O’s and a much strong battery like a 3.6V Li-Ion 18650 cell

Comment: The 2 LEDs can be back-back on 2 pins

Comment: Thanks again Tony - this is really a solution to a problem that literally no one has! It's for a game to indicate active/inactive characters - currently we face them forward or backward which really is the easiest way. I thought it would be fun to have an LED imbedded in the character base that could show different colors. It seems unnecessarily complicated for me - who again, has zero experience working with this stuff! :)

Comment: The reality is the battery storage time is about a day, with a CR2032, that's WHY you haven't seen it.  You can try any LED across a coin cell directly and the battery internal resistance will limit the current safely. and decay quickly for half a day then be very dim for days after 1 day.

Comment: A real  green LED (i.e. 525nm) MUST be run at a low current to get the Vf down below 3V.  I recommend the  Cree C503B for both red and green for bright output at low currents.  The HLMP-Y is an ugly inefficient  565 nm  yellow-green (very yellow, hardly green) .  The Cree green at 2 mA will have 5,000 mcd at 2.8V with a 100 Ω resistor and 93% efficiency.   And because the CR2032 has a flat discharge curve it will last nearly to the battery's cuttoff.   Still more light and longer battery life.  It could be run at 100 µA and still be as bright as the HLMP.

Comment: I agree  on the LED choice. I just did a quick look for GaP green But his battery replacement rate will be too high to be practical.